# unit test Spring MissingServletRequestParameterException JSON response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc, spring-restcontroller, jsonresponse

I have POST method in a Spring boot rest controller as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/post/action/bookmark", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> bookmarkPost(
        @RequestParam(value="actionType",required=true) String actionType,
        @RequestParam(value="postId",required=true) String postId,
        @CurrentUser User user) throws Exception{
    return service.bookmarkPost(postId, actionType, user);
}
```

now if I test with missing parameter in *Postman* I get an 400 http response and a JSON body:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2015-07-20",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
  "message": "Required String parameter 'actionType' is not present",
  "path": "/post/action/bookmark"
}
```

until now it's OK, but when I try to unit test I don't get the JSON response back

```
@Test
public void bookmarkMissingActionTypeParam() throws Exception{
    // @formatter:off
    mockMvc.perform(
                post("/post/action/bookmark")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .param("postId", "55ab8831036437e96e8250b6")
                    )
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.exception", containsString("MissingServletRequestParameterException")));
    // @formatter:on
}
```

the test fails and produces

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
```

I did a **.andDo(print())** and found that there is no body in the response

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 400
   Error message = Required String parameter 'actionType' is not present
         Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[1], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
    Content type = null
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

why am I not getting the JSON response while unit testing my controller, but do receive it in manual testing using Postman or cUrl?

EDIT: I've added *@WebIntegrationTest* but got the same error:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RestApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class PostControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }  

    @Test
    public void bookmarkMissingActionTypeParam() throws Exception{
        // @formatter:off
        mockMvc.perform(
                    post("/post/action/bookmark")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("postId", "55ab8831036437e96e8250b6")
                        )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.exception", containsString("MissingServletRequestParameterException")));
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue with a non error response as well: have you had any success with this?

Comment: No, not yet.. I skipped testing these cases!

Answer (score 3):

This is because Spring Boot has auto-configured an exception handler `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController` which is probably not present in your unit tests. A way to get it will be to use the Spring Boot testing support related annotations:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@WebIntegrationTest
```

More details are [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

**Update**: 
You are absolutely right, the behavior is very different in UI vs in test, the error pages which respond to status codes are not correctly hooked up in a non-servlet test environment. Improving this behavior can be a good bug to open for Spring MVC and/or Spring Boot.

For now, I have a workaround which simulates the behavior of `BasicErrorController` the following way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {RestApplication.class, TestConfiguration.class})
@WebIntegrationTest
public class PostControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }  

    @Test
    public void bookmarkMissingActionTypeParam() throws Exception{
        // @formatter:off
        mockMvc.perform(
                    post("/post/action/bookmark")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .param("postId", "55ab8831036437e96e8250b6")
                        )
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.exception", containsString("MissingServletRequestParameterException")));
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
     @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public ErrorController errorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
            return new ErrorController(errorAttributes);
        }
    }
@ControllerAdvice
class ErrorController extends BasicErrorController {

    public ErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes);
    }

    @Override
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return super.error(request);
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is adding a `ControllerAdvice` which handles the Exception flow and delegates back to the `BasicErrorController`. This would atleast make the behavior consistent for you.

Comment: I've added *@WebIntegrationTest* but got the same error, I've added the full Test class above

Comment: Just for my information, does your `RestApplication` have the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

Comment: nope, using '@SpringBootApplication' only.. isn't that equivalent?

Comment: You are right, I have added an update with a potential workaround

Comment: tried putting TestConfiguration outside PostControllerTest (but in the same file" and didn't compile because of static, same thing if I added TestConfiguration inside PostControllerTest (@SpringApplicationConfiguration cannot resolve TestConfiguration to a type)
last I added TestConfiguration in a seperate file and removed static, i'm getting "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.rest.ErrorController.<init>()"

Comment: I am facing the same issue and still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Originally, it should fix the error by `@ResponseBody` tag when defining your REST controller method. it will fix json error in the test class.
But, as you are using spring boot, you will define the controller class with `@RestController` and it should automatically take care of the error without defining `@Controller` and `@ResponseType` tags.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and this answer doesn't help, @Biju understand them problem the correct way.